# How to extends php.snippets to html in Ultisnips?

Tags: plugin-ultisnips

I want to enable html snippets for php files. The Ultisnips manual said what I need to do is put `extends html` command at the beginning of the `php.snippets` file. But it doesn't work. HTML snippets still aren't showing up. How do I extend it properly?

Answer (score 4):

It's difficult to point out where your problem is, since you didn't really
describe what *exactly* you did; but this is how I added a custom PHP snippet
file:

- I installed http://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips and http://github.com/honza/vim-snippets
- I created `~/.vim/UltiSnips/php.snippets` with the contents:

  ```
  extends php, html

  snippet 42
  The universe, life, and everything
  endsnippet
  ```
- After opening a new Vim, I can use `42<Tab>`, and the standard PHP
  snippets (eg. `if<Tab>`), and HTML snippets (eg. `div<Tab>`).

See `:help UltiSnips-adding-snippets` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You did the opposite. You should have written `extends php` in your `html.snippets` file. Then you can open a myfile.php and start using html snippets.